# DBset<> no contiene una definicio para toList ASP.NET EF C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hola amigos estoy tratando de hacer esto, pero no se porque me da este error, alguien sabe a que se deba? segun yo podria hacerlo muy tanquilamente, cabe destacar que uso **Entity Framework** para mi consulta y db.alumnos_ es una de mis tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 public JsonResult GetUsers()
        {

            using (elitestappEntities db = new elitestappEntities())
            {

                var alumnos = db.alumnos_.ToList<alumnoModel>();
                    //.ToList<alumnoModel>().All();

                return Json(alumnos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

```
namespace apptest33.Models
{
    public class alumnoModel
    {
        public int id_cartera { set; get; }
      public int id_cliente { set; get; }
      public string status { set; get; }
        public string created_at { set; get; }
        public string name { set; get; }
        public string lastnameP { set; get; }
        public string lastnameM { set; get; }
        public string alergias { set; get; }
        public string tiposangre { set; get; }
        public string talla { set; get; }
        public string peso { set; get; }
        public string precede { set; get; }
        public string  clave { set; get; }
        public string colegiatura { set; get; }
        public string seguro { set; get; }
        public string grado { set; get; }
        public string nivel { set; get; }
        public string observaciones { set; get; }
        public string sexo { set; get; }
        public string promocion { set; get; }
        public string estado { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado con `db.alumnos_.ToList();` ?

Answer (score 0):

ToList() es un método de Extension para toda clase que implementa la interface `IEnumerable` y se encuentra en Linq.

Para poder utilizarlo debes incluir el namespace correspondiente entre las listas de using al principio del documento:

```
using System.Linq;
namespace ...
{
    public class ...
    {
        public JsonResult GetUsers()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: estoy usando linq y todo esto using apptest33.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;
using apptest33.BD;

Comment: Acabo de notar que no se trata de que falta el metodo `ToList()` porque en el error se menciona una sugerencia. Por favor puedes publicar la línea de código donde defines el DBSet de alumnos.  Me da la impresión que no es del mismo tipo de AlumnosModel.

Comment: agregue el modelo pero no tengo un dbset

Comment: otra cosa usa EF para conectarme a mi bd y pues de ahi vienen las referencias de mis tablas

Comment: En EF, el DbSet está representado por una propiedad dentro de la clase que implementa DbContext, encontrarás algo parecido a: `public DbSet<...> alumnos_ { get; set; }`.

Comment: podrias modificar tu respuesta para ver como quedaria?

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim, necesito ver la definición del DbSet de alumnos, yo sospecho que la causa del error puede estar relacionada con eso pero sin ver esa declaración no lo podré confirmar. Mi comentario anterior es una pista que te doy para que lo encuentres.